# Creating a form that lets users select an image on the page

Tags: jquery, html, forms, xhtml

Attached is a screen shot of a portion of my page which I am trying to code. I want the user to be able to click an image and that selection is recorded and then sent to me so I know which design they like best.

I don't want the user have to type anything, just click an image and send the form. I'll be using jQuery to reveal the users selection in the "You Choose..." section, but I am totally unsure of how to get their selection recorded in a form so I can send the results through email once they press the submit button.

I have many of these sections and images for the users to choose from. I know I can simply put a radio button below each image but is there a way I can do without the radio buttons and record their selections with just a click on the image itself? Maybe a combination of radio buttons and the image?

Thanks.[image]

Comment: You can do radio buttons, but what do you want displayed in the email sent to you? Just the name of the template they send or the image itself? If it's just text, it is quite easy, adding an images is easy too, just not as easy, because then you have to send the email as HTML and not just plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this :

```
<img class="bamBoum" src="blabvla.jpg" alt="" title="" data-id="1" />

var prefImage = 0;
$('.bamBoum').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    prefImage = $(this).attr('data-id');

    alert(prefImage)
});
```

When you "submit" the page, just look into the variable.

Of course, you have to remember your webpage will require Javascript to work. You could populate an hidden field with the variable also so when you submit your form, you can see the result on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of ways. You can use radios as you mentioned, but just hide them. Just remember set visibility to hidden, or absolutely position off the screen; using `display: none` will actually not submit their values with the form, defeating the purpose.

Or, you could use a hidden input, and store the selected choice in that.

Or, if you didn't mind the form submitting as soon as they chose, you could even use `<input type="image">`, giving each the same name, but unique values. That's probably not the best way to go about it, but it is technically a way.

Answer (score 0):

You could populate a hidden field with the selection's value prior to the submission of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browsers you need to support, this could be a nice place to use the [ol' checkbox hack](http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/). Instead of checkboxes, you'd use radios.

Comment: I'll point out that it's far easier (but much less fun!) to just bind a listener to your images' `onclick` events and use that to create/update a hidden form input to record the value of their selection.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) then you can build your post data with variables instead of input fields.

And to find which one is selected, you can either do this by finding which one has the respective selected class to it, or use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to store the last one selected, during a [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event.